# React and Express application running on Elastic Beanstalk cannot get route after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a React / Express application running on an Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance. The application works fine, and the routing within the application works as expected. However anytime I reload/refresh the window, I get this error displayed:

```
{"genericError":"The requested route does not exist","status":404}
```

And I can not for the life of me figure this out. I am not even sure what I should post, so I am going to post the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` here:

```
branch-defaults:
  development:
    environment: XX
    group_suffix: null
  master:
    environment: XX
    group_suffix: null
  production:
    environment: XX
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: XX
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Node.js
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

And the `.ebextensions/staticfiles.config`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
    /public: /public
```

Please let me know if I need to post something more specific. Thanks for looking, always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved. I had removed the catch-all route in my Express server to serve the `build/index.html` file. Found it in a previous branch, and realized what happened. Here it is for anyone else in the future:

This is declared after your routes, and before your error handler(s).

```
//Catch All Route
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});
```